# "No module named 'otworz'"

Tags: python, module

`otworz` is a module that I created **in a separate folder** and the program that I created is **in the same folder** and supposed to `import` it and use it (by opening the Google Chrome browser, at the moment). However, the interpreter says that there is no such module. Here's my code:

```
import os

chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

def open_p(program):
    os.startfile(program)
```

*(the function's called `open_p` because `open` is already a function)*

```
import otworz

otworz.open_p(otworz.chrome)
```

Comment: How are these files arranged? Do you have any `__init__.py` files? Is the directory on your Python path? As it stands, there's not much to go on.

Comment: They are both in a random folder, and the module's name `__otworz__.py`. Just them two.

Comment: Well no wonder it can't find it! What's with the underscores?! Please read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe One, I'm using Python 3, two can you explain what you mean by underscores

Comment: 1. Then read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html (it was one letter! Also, you can pick versions from the drop-down at the top-left of Python docs pages) and 2. `_`.

Comment: I know what the underscore is, but if it is a module, I think I need it, don't I?

Comment: No, why would you? Double leading and trailing underscores indicate Python internals; you *could* use them (then `import __otworz__`), but why bother?! Again, **read the tutorial**: *"The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended."*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73017/discussion-between-krystian-mikolajczyk-and-jonrsharpe).